# Característica "Deploy Database To a Microsoft Azure VM", ¿disponible en SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment, sql-server-2008-r2

¿Se puede usar la característica *Deploy Database To a Microsoft Azure VM* en SQL Server 2008 R2? ¿O solamente está disponible a partir de SQL Server 2012 en adelante?

Actualmente estoy usando SQL Server 2008 R2 y quiero desplegar una o mas bases de datos a mi máquina virtual de Azure que tiene instalado SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no es posible. Esa función solo está disponible de SQL Server 2014 en adelante.

Referencia: [Implementar una base de datos de SQL Server en una máquina virtual de Microsoft Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn195938.aspx), o en inglés [Deploy a SQL Server Database to a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195938.aspx).

> Esta característica de implementación está disponible en SQL Server Management Studio para SQL Server 2016 y SQL Server 2014.

Es cierto que un poco mas abajo dice lo siguiente:

> Las versiones de la base de datos de SQL Server que se pueden implementar en la máquina virtual de Windows Azure con este asistente son:
>
> - SQL Server 2008
> - SQL Server 2008 R2
> - SQL Server 2012
> - SQL Server 2014
> - SQL Server 2016

Pero esto se refiere a bases de datos que corren en SQL Server 2014 o 2016, pero con el *Compatibility level* de una versión anterior. No creo que aplique a tu caso.